# Including MooTools in HTML

Tags: mootools

If I have some Mootools script, do I include the script in HTML like so?

```
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent("domready", function(){
        $$('div.rj_insertcode a.glossarylink, .no_glossary a.glossarylink').each(function(el) {
                new Element("span", {
                    html: el.get("html")
                }).replaces(el);
    });  
    });   
    </script>
    </head>
```

I am using Joomla with "System - Mootools Upgrade" plugin enabled (so MT 1.2.4 is already included and ready to use).

Comment: If your question is incorrect, you can [always edit it.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4873137/1228)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using Joomla with "System - Mootools Upgrade" plugin enabled (so MT 1.2.4 is already included and ready to use).

if mootools is already included then your domready script block needs to be after the call to include mootools so its symbols and methods are defined.

typically:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent("domready", function() {
    // code here
});
</script>
```

if your script is unlikely to produce anything that relates to template variables you are outputting and you just work the DOM, then I'd suggest moving it to an external .js file instead.

Other best practices ATM seem to point to putting all js at the bottom so it's non-blocking and faster but this negates the point of domready as by the time you run the js all page elements are defined, it won't fire any earlier (you can reference dom already).

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="your-mootools-file.js"></script>
```